# Visual Studio Extensibility Package 2010 and 2012. Is there a way to have one package for both?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

A while ago I created a Visual Studio Package/Add-In for Visual Studio 2010 (for those curious: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ea23f9a7-a942-45b2-87e6-5df6ff0444ff). If I try to download that and install it in Visual Studio 2012, it doesn't work, I get a version error.

So my first thought was to see what happens if I try to port it to 2012. I downloaded and installed the VS2012 RC SDK, and basically recreated the whole thing in a separate solution and it all works. What I noticed was that many of the assemblies I had to reference (Microsoft.VisualStudio.*) were now version 11 as opposed to version 10 (for obvious reasons). After copying and pasting all the code over, I got it to work correctly in Visual Studio 2012.

My question now is this: Is it possible to have one .vsix file for multiple versions of Visual Studio (I'm guessing no.) If not, what's the correct approach to take as far as uploading the different versions? Can I upload two versions of a .vsix? Will the Add-In manager in visual studio pick the correct one automatically? Do I need to create a new package e.g. "Visual Pastie 2012"? Just looking for some guidance.

Comment: AFAIK, a VS2010 vsix should work in VS2012. Not the other way around though.

Comment: Here is the best answer I found on the topic: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22688894/27194

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rename the VSIX package to give it a ZIP extension and open it up. You'll find a file called extension.vsixmanifest. Inside this XML file you'll find an element called SupportedProducts which should look like the following to work in VS2012.

```
  <SupportedProducts>
    <VisualStudio Version="11.0">
      <Edition>Pro</Edition>
    </VisualStudio>
  </SupportedProducts>
```

HTH

Comment: Forgot to accept it. This is what I ended up doing, added both version 10 and version 11 in that xml node. Thanks!!